# Why am I getting Dart Error: Undefined name 'yas'?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
main() {
  CarsB cars = CarsB(lastname: 'Uysal', firstname: 'Kerem');
  print(cars.firstname);
}

class Cars {
  String firstname = '';
  String lastname = '';
  int yas = 0;
  Cars(
    this.yas, {
    this.firstname = '',
    this.lastname = '',
  });
}

class CarsB extends Cars {
  CarsB({String firstname = '', String lastname = ''})
      : super(yas, firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname);
}
```

Why am I getting an error?

Error is:

```
Error: Undefined name 'yas'.
main.dart:51
      : super(yas, firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname);
              ^^^
Exited (254)
```

Comment: Where is yas defined in CarsB?

Answer (score 0):

```
CarsB({String firstname = '', String lastname = ''})
      : super(yas, firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname);
```

Your CarsB constructor does not have a parameter called `yas`. So passing `yas` to the super constructor is a mistake. The compiler does not know what to do with it. When I call `final b = CarsB(firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Doe');` what do you expect `yas` to be? It is undefined. And your compiler cannot compile that.